# Xcode puts Default.png in my plist as an Icon file when I assign a Launch Image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

When I set a `Launch Image`, Xcode creates a copy as `Default.png` and creates an entry in my `plist` in Icon Files (`iOS 5) / Primary Icon / Icon Items --> Item 1 : Default.png`

`Item 0 : MyIcon.png` is the app icon which I have already placed through the Target.

The reason this is a problem is that the launch image then takes precedence over the actual icon and as a result, it shows as the primary icon instead of my actual icon image.

Why is Xcode doing this?
Can I safely delete the `Default.png` entry from my .`plist`? (this seems to fix the problem)
Do I need to copy `Default.png` somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also an alternate way. Follow this simple step:

[image]

Comment: This is actually what I did first for the app icon and the launch image. And when I do this for the launch image, Xcode still copies Default.png as a value into my .plist. Then when I run my app on my device, the launch image replaces my app icon image. Oddly, this does not seem to happen in my simulator. Thoughts?

Comment: remove the app icon and launch image from project by using move to thrash. Then follow this solution again. Don't use same name icon/image twice in a project. It can create reference problem for compiler.

Comment: Ok, I tried this too and it doesn't seem to fix the issue. The app appears fine in the simulator but the icon on the device is the launch image instead of the actual icon. I can't find any documentation or other SO posts on this topic. The only thing that seems to work is deleting the .plist entry for Default.png. Can I safely do this?

Comment: If I just place Default.png in the target window and don't manually drop it in the summary, everything works. Strange. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the Default.png file. Select it again in the summary section project's target settings. you can also drag drop it the on the icon of launch image in the summary section.

Comment: Yes, but should Xcode be setting Default.png in my .plist. Why is it doing that?

Comment: It doesn't always do that. You have to specify yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that if you are developing and app for iOS 5, there are two different sections for declaring your icons.  The Info editor in the Project editor doesn't show the iOS 5 section.  You have to load the file in the Property List editor.

Basically for pre-iOS 5 there is 'CFBundleIconFiles', for iOS 5+ it's 'CFBundleIcons'

Make sure that these have the same icon files names in them.